# Plotly markers to appear in a bar chart

Tags: r, plotly

I am new to plotly and want to make my own bullet chart (a bit like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961) that has markers/traces to show the values of the relevant values when comparing actual vs expected.

Below is my attempt:

```
q <- ggplot(data.frame(measure='',actual=25),aes(x=measure,y=actual))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  ylim(c(0,35))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 30,color='red')+
  geom_text(y=30,label='Expected',angle=270,vjust=0)+
  coord_flip()+
  ylab('Num. of carrots')
q
q1 <- ggplotly(q) %>% add_markers()
q1
```

When converting it to plotly using `ggplotly`, the text looks like it has not rotated correctly, and the markers/traces do not show for the bar chart...Any help here would be much appreciated.

Kindest regards,

HLM

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that plotly supports rotating text for type="scatter" (which is how ggplotly is interpreting your `geom_text`). You can delete the `geom_text` line from the ggplot graph, then add text to the plotly one using annotations:

```
q1 <- ggplotly(q) %>% add_markers() %>%
  layout(annotations = list(x = 30, y = 1,  text = "Expected", textangle=270))
q1
```

[image]

### update

The 2nd part of your question (how to also get hover info on the bar) is slightly trickier. To get the hover info, we can create the bars using the plotly API directly like this

```
p.bars = plot_ly(data = data.frame(measure='', actual=25)) %>% 
           add_bars(y=~measure, x=~actual, orientation="h")
```

we can add the text annotation to it like this

```
p.bars.text = p.bars %>% 
              layout(annotations = list(x = 30, y = 0,  text = "Expected", textangle=270, 
                     showarrow=F, xanchor="center"))
```

But the problem is that adding a line also to this plot by

```
 p.bars.text %>% add_segments(x=30, xend=30, y=-0.5, yend=0.5)
```

gives an error

> Error in populate_categorical_axes(p) : Can't display both discrete & non-discrete data on same axis

I.e. we can only specify the y values of the line with respect to categorical values of y.  So, for example we can do

```
dat1 = data.frame(measure=letters[1:2], actual=c(25,20))
plot_ly(data = dat1) %>% 
  add_bars(y=~measure, x=~actual, orientation="h") %>%
  layout(annotations = list(x = 29, y = 0,  text = "Expected", textangle=270, 
                            showarrow=F, xanchor="center")) %>%
  add_segments(x=30, xend=30, y='a', yend='b')
```

which gives the following in which the line is aligned with the category labels rather than with the width of the bars

[image]

The only solution I have to this at the moment is to use a numeric axis for the categories, and then set the axis labels using ticktext:

```
plot_ly(data = data.frame(measure=c(0,1), actual=c(25,20))) %>% 
  add_bars(y=~measure, x=~actual, orientation="h", showlegend=F) %>%
  add_segments(x=30, xend=30, y=-0.4, yend=0.4, showlegend=F)  %>%
  layout(annotations = list(x = 29.5, y = 0,  text = "Expected", textangle=270, showarrow=F, xanchor="center"),
         yaxis = list(tickmode="array", tickvals=c(0,1), ticktext=c("", "") ))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of how the above will use the plotly API directly then?

Comment: The example you gave still doesn't show 25 as the trace/marker value at the edge of the bar...

Comment: Sorry - i'm a little unclear what you want to show - there is no '25' marker in the original ggplot version in your question either. Do you mean that you want hover info on the bar, or that you need another text annotation on the end of the bar?

Comment: Yes sorry, my mistake. I assumed that the hover info was the trace/markers. I don't think i need another text annotation, as I believe that is static..., I was hoping it would appear once hovered over...

Comment: See update - I think I have a full answer now to both parts of your two-pronged question

Comment: @h.l.m Is there a problem with this answer? Surprised to see that you did not even find it worthy of an upvote.

Comment: your response has two horizontal bars, I was hoping for something that has a single bar like my original example.

Comment: The two bars were to show how the category labels affect the placement of the lines. Difficult to demonstrate that effectively with only one bar. Of course you can make it just one bar very simply, by just deleting one row of the data frame (there is one bar for each row). I leave that as an exercise for you, as I think that the above already solves the question you asked, and changing it will not really assist anyone else who looks at this answer.